# I want to donate Kodak 35mm equipment to a non profit

Tags: kodak

I have a complete Kodak 35mm projector (in carrying case),carousels and a screen. I want to donate them to a non profit or school. Any ideas about where to list these items?
Any members want to make suggestions?

These are available for pickup in Seattle.

Comment: While I thoroughly approve of your goal here, unfortunately Stack Exchange isn't the place to ask this kind of question. Consider a more traditional photography forum, maybe [DPReview](https://www.dpreview.com/) given their obvious association with Seattle.

Comment: ...or a non-photography, local website

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about making photographs and it is too localized.

Comment: The lamps used in slide projectors are expensive and are getting more difficult to locate. Even O/H projectors are becoming rare.

Answer (score 6):

A library might be a better option. People are always trying to give their old computers and whatnot to schools, when what schools need is up-to-date equipment. Teachers these days probably don't have a lot of 35mm slides to show, but they do a lot with PowerPoint presentations on digital displays.

A community library is more likely to have resources on old media like slides and 8mm or 16mm film. The local historical society would be another good option, for the same reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You could list it on [Freecycle](http://freecycle.org), and state your preference for a non-profit.  Be aware that anyone could misrepresent themselves.